# Mock a service to return an empty list to test 404 status code

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit, mocking

I've attempting to test this REST service such that a NOT_FOUND (404) error is thrown when `itemService.getActiveItems()` returns an empty `List`:

```
@GetMapping("/items/active")
public ResponseEntity<List<ItemEntity>> getActiveItems() {

    List<ItemEntity> activeItems = itemService.getActiveItems();
    if (activeItems.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(activeItems, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I use the TestRestTemplate to test :

```
     @Mock
     private ItemService itemService;
    
            @Test
            public void activeItemsTest() {
            private TestRestTemplate templateAuth;
        
        when(itemService.getActiveItems()).thenReturn(new ArrayList());
            
                    ResponseEntity<List<ItemEntity>> result = templateAuth.exchange("/items/active", HttpMethod.GET,
                            null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ItemEntity>>() {
                            });
                    Assertions.assertThat(result.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
```

I'm trying to cause the `"/items/active"` endpoint to return `new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);` as I have mocked `itemService.getActiveItems()` to return an empty `ArrayList`. When I test `result.getStatusCode()` does not contain 404. How should I amend my test in order to return a 404 error code ?

Comment: So what does activeItems contain when you test this?

Comment: You need to fix up your `activeItemsTest(){}` You have `private TestRestTemplate templateAuth;` inside.

Comment: If you can go with junit5, you may want to take a look at this example. You can @autowire the actual service class, resttempalte..etc:  https://gist.github.com/Jet-C/6c4d3ebf91f8d6d6ccba0468c2dbef95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JUnit 5 and annotate the class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`
and `@SpringBootTest`. Then change

```
 @Mock
 private ItemService itemService;
```

to

```
 @SpyBean
 private ItemService itemService;
```

so that you can mock the behaviour of the service that is autowired into the Controller